# Rails Console Error Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I just recently updated Ruby(2.3.1) and Rails(5.0.0.1). Now, when I get an error ( any type of error) on the rails console, it's followed by about 15-20 lines starting with 'from/Users....../.rvm/..etc'. Any idea why I am getting so many lines of this error output and if it's normal? How could I fix it? Everything else regarding Ruby/Rails works perfectly fine for me otherwise, so maybe it's just normal output. However, it is a bit of an annoyance.

The commonality in each path seems to be '.rvm'. 
For example:

```
  2.3.1 :031 > test
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
    from (irb):31:in `test'
    from (irb):31
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
2.3.1 :032 >
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails console uses IRB under the covers, so you're going to have to edit your IRB configuration file, usually located at `~/irbrc`, and change the `BACK_TRACE_LIMIT` value:

```
IRB.conf[:BACK_TRACE_LIMIT]=0
```

During a Rails console session, you can also run:

```
conf.back_trace_limit = 0
```

There are many more configuration options for IRB (and by extension, Rails console).  Check them out at [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration).